# python - pandas: count identical values per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as follow:

```
                          investing.com                                  ft                      bloomberg
19        API Weekly Distillates Stocks                                 NaN                                 NaN
20            API Weekly Gasoline Stock                                 NaN                                 NaN
21                                  NaN         Advance Goods Trade Balance         Advance Goods Trade Balance
22                                  NaN                                 NaN                Advance Retail Sales
23                        All Car Sales                                 NaN                                 NaN
24                      All Truck Sales                                 NaN                                 NaN
25          Average Hourly Earnings MoM         Average Hourly Earnings MoM         Average Hourly Earnings MoM
26                                  NaN                                 NaN         Average Hourly Earnings YoY
```

i would like to add a column with a count of all the values that are not NaN.

I tried:

`df['count of not NaN'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x[['investing.com','ft','bloomberg']] != 'NaN').count(), axis=1)`

but it did not work. Anyone knows why / can help me with the correct formula?
(I know some flavors of this question have already been posted, but they can't really help me get to a successful outcome...)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count method does exactly this. Use it with axis=1 to add a column.

```
df.count(axis=1)
```

Comment: yes.. sorry silly question.. I was about to delete it as i had found the answer just now.. anyway.